# How to fix " Failed to compile Unexpected token { " error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, babel-loader

I cloned a program written using typescript + react and I tried running the codebase but I got this error "Failed to compile. Unexpected token {" which occurred during build time and I don't know how to fix it. I tried installing babel-preset-react but no changes to the error. I've gone through similar questions but none solves my problem. How can I resolve this?

Here is my package.JSON

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "@testing-library/dom": "^7.26.3",
        "@types/lodash": "^4.14.159",
        "@types/react-custom-scrollbars": "^4.0.7",
        "@types/reactstrap": "^8.4.3",
        "@types/testing-library__dom": "^7.5.0",
        "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
        "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
        "class-validator": "^0.12.2",
        "connected-react-router": "^6.8.0",
        "formik": "^2.1.4",
        "framer-motion": "^2.8.0",
        "jquery": "^3.5.1",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "mobx": "^6.0.1",
        "moment": "^2.27.0",
        "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
        "react": "^16.13.1",
        "react-custom-scrollbars": "^4.2.1",
        "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
        "react-feather": "^2.0.8",
        "react-icons": "^3.11.0",
        "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
        "react-router": "^5.2.0",
        "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
        "react-scripts": "^4.0.0",
        "reactstrap": "^8.5.1",
        "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
        "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
        "styled-components": "^5.1.1",
        "typescript": "~3.7.2"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject",
        "lint": "eslint ./src/**/*.ts ./src/**/*.tsx",
        "postinstall": "rm -rf node_modules/@types/react-native"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": "react-app"
    },
    "browserslist": {
        "production": [
            ">0.2%",
            "not dead",
            "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
            "last 1 chrome version",
            "last 1 firefox version",
            "last 1 safari version"
        ]
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
        "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
        "@types/jest": "^24.0.19",
        "@types/node": "^14.11.8",
        "@types/react": "^16.9.51",
        "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.8",
        "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.9",
        "@types/react-router": "^5.1.8",
        "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.5",
        "@types/styled-components": "^4.1.8",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^3.6.0"
    },
    "babel": {
        "presets": [ "react", "es2015"]
    }
}
```

Here is a picture of the entire error message displayed
[image]

From the inspector tool, it made reference to line 1 of index.js file (in react-error-overlay) in node_modules containing this

```
!function(e, t) {
   "object" == typeof exports && "object" == typeof module ? module.exports = t() : "function" == typeof define && define.amd ? define([], t) : "object" == typeof exports ? exports.ReactErrorOverlay = t() : e.ReactErrorOverlay = t()
}(window, (function() {
    return function(e) {
        var t = {};
        function n(r) {
            if (t[r])
                return t[r].exports;
            var u = t[r] = {
                i: r,
                l: !1,
                exports: {}
            };
            return e[r].call(u.exports, u, u.exports, n),
            u.l = !0,
            u.exports
        } ...
```

**note: this is a minified code**

Comment: Sorry if this is a stupid question, but did you run npm install first? I'm also wondering if there are any other services such as an api server that you need to run in parallel for it to function.

Comment: Its not a stupid question Brandon and yes I did run npm install first, I kept getting series of errors which I fixed until this

Comment: Errors like *Unexpected token* usually comes with a line number and a file on which this happens. Could you edit the full error in your question?

Comment: There was no added message to the error

Comment: is there a file referenced ? could you log the message or make a picture of the full error please ?

Comment: you need to open the inspector on your browser to get a more descriptive error

Comment: okay, let me do that